# How to fix memory leak prevention this source?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

[image]

My app sometimes dies. That's why I check logcat. 
It's mostly a `GC` and `OutOfMemory` problem.

That's why I use Allocation Tracking on android studio.
In this picture, I check where memory leak occurs.

I don't know how to prevent memory leak on android.

Memory leak is caused by using record camera preview.

I record camera preview using https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile library.
My source: https://github.com/c004245/memoryLeakRecordModule

Please help me.

thanks.

@update

If you need my errorlog.

https://github.com/c004245/memoryLeakRecordModule   errorlog.txt download.

Thanks.

Comment: try Leak Canary Library and it will tell you where is the leak exactly in a more precise way

Comment: @MeknessiHamida I know Leak Canary Library exactly where is the leak. but Allocation Tracking exactly where is the leak

Comment: Would you re-phrase it please I didn't undrestand you. Through you errorlog it says `Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@3bc3c57 that was originally bound here`  is that a part of your code ? You have a time listener do you unregistrered when you no longer need it ?

Comment: @MeknessiHamida   I check unregistered part,   first service error my code.

Comment: `first service error my code` ???? I didn't undrestand you